# Does GRUB show the boot menu after kernel updates?

Tags: grub2, kernel

This is **NOT** a **dual boot** question.

If only one single OS is installed GRUB does not show the boot menu by default.
It can be adjusted to show the boot menu whenever desired.

Reference : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Does the GRUB menu appear after any kernel updates ?
Do kernel updates trigger GRUB to show the boot menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically , no. After kernel install Ubuntu does run a script to reconfigure grub, so that it's menu is updated to include new kernel as the main entry and push the older entries into Advanced Options for Ubuntu menu.

What may have happened is that you have edited at some point `/etc/default/grub` file , but didn't not run `sudo update-grub`, so everything stayed the old way. New kernel arrived, ran that `update-grub` command, and now it shows the menu.

I doubt the updates contain any command to change grub settings, and I'd be very surprised if they do

Comment: that means kernel updates never trigger grub menu unless untill we do something before ?

Comment: Yes, specifically edit `/etc/default/grub` file before. Otherwise no change